# Python Thread in OpenCV

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv

Why this code do not run parallel ? Until this process is completed next functions do not start.
If i try run after this thread other functions ( webview.start() ) the window do not show until opencv not stoped

```
def videoLoop(video_capture, face_cascade, anterior):
    while True:
        if not video_capture.isOpened():
            print('Unable to load camera.')
            sleep(5)
            pass

        ret, frame = video_capture.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(
            gray,
            scaleFactor=1.1,
            minNeighbors=5,
            minSize=(30, 30)
        )
        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

        if anterior != len(faces):
            todo()

        cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break



def faceDetect():
    cascPath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
    faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)
    log.basicConfig(filename='faces.log',level=log.INFO)
    video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    anterior = 0

    if not video_capture.isOpened():
        print("err")
    else:
        thread1 = Thread(target=videoLoop(video_capture, faceCascade, anterior), daemon=True)
        thread1.start()
        thread1.join()
```

Comment: Did you try to use a small `sleep()` in your while loop? It might give time for the other tasks to execute.

Comment: I'm tryed do not use loop but until this process not done main program wait